# Lambda copying a reference to a lambda reference VS2017 compile error

Tags: c++, lambda

Compiling the following code in Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int test = 5;

    auto cb1 = [test]()
    {
        auto cb2 = [&]()
        {
            auto cb3 = [test]()
            {
                std::cout << test;
            };
            cb3();
        };
        cb2();
    };
    cb1();
}
```

Gives the compiler error

```
test.cpp(17): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'const int' to 'main::<lambda_80fd0d4feae1377a5d8b8955e10105ab>::()::<lambda_38fc83ae6a7bd6540ebe1721869db4f1>'
test.cpp(17): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
test.cpp(18): error C3536: 'cb2': cannot be used before it is initialized
test.cpp(18): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
```

Does anybody know why Visual Studio gives this error? (it seem to compile ok on clang) You can get it to compile by replacing `auto cb2 = [&]()` with `auto cb2 = [&test]()` why does that fix the errors?

Even more interesting adding `std::cout << test;` or `const int &ref = test;` to the body of `cb2` fixes the compiler error.

Comment: Due to the fact, that [G++ accepts such code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SDrHJ1SQ7DbFC02e), I suspect that it's a bug in VS2017, unless it's some form of UB, that I don't know about.

Comment: Looks like MSVS isn't treating the treating the use of `test` in the capture of `cb3` as a valid reason to capture `test` in`cb2`.  Not sure who is right in this case but I'm inclined to think the gcc is behaving correctly.

Comment: I can reproduce this. My guess would be that the parser is confused about what `[&]` captures - it apparently tries to capture the implicit `this` (the `cb1` instance that `cb2` is in) on the one hand, but tries to initialize it with `test` directly. All your fixes probably alleviate that confusion. But in the end it's a bug in MSVC either way.

Comment: Weird... Changing the lambda capture of `cb3` to `&test` seems to do the job. https://rextester.com/FEFQ33220

Answer (score 1):

This is just a bug in older Visual Studio compilers. One can see experimentally that the error was present till MSVC v16.10, and it was fixed in MSVC v16.11. Fortunately,  modern compilers including Visual Studio 2019 accept your program. Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rYG7Ma8n9